# A subgroup $H$ of $G$ must contain the identity from $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

I was given the following definition of a subgroup: Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subset of $G$. We say that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $H$ is a group under the same operation from $G$.

I was told that this easily implies that the identity from $G$ must also be in $H$, but I can't see this. I get that the subset must then be closed on the same operation. I get that the operation is associative. I get that there must be some identity, but I can't see how the identity in $H$ must be the same as the identity in $G$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume $e_H$ is an identity in $H.$ Then $e_H*e_H=e_H.$ Multiplying both sides with the inverse of $e_H$ in $G$ we get $e_H=e_G,$ where $e_G$ is the identity in $G.$

Comment: Nice way of seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $H$ is not empty, $h\in H$; now $hh^{-1}=1_H=1_G$.

Comment: Hmm, I think there is a problem in this answer. How do you know that $h^{-1}$ is in $H$?

Comment: Seems like missing the point. Since $H$ is a group it has an identity - the question is why $1_h=1_G$. Not that that's hard, of course...

Comment: @Mark $H$ is a subgroup, so we know inverses in $H$ exist, but we don't know a priori that the inverse of $h$ in $H$ is the same as the inverse of $h$ in $G$.

Comment: @kccu, yes, this is exactly what I wrote in the comment. $h^{-1}$ is the inverse of $h$ in $G$. It is not that trivial that it equals to the inverse in $H$. (easy to prove that, but it still has to be proved)

Comment: I think that for $h$ having an inverse you should first show that $e$ is in $H$ or assume since it is a group not the other way around.